# How to communicate with Cylon BMS controller

Tags: python, iot, bacnet

I try to communicate with Cylon device (UC32) by Bacnet protocol (`BAC0`) but I can not discover any device. And I try with Yabe and it does not have any result.
Is there any document describing how to create my communication driver?
Or any technique which can be uswed to connect with this device?

Comment: BAC0 is not the protocol, but the port that the protocol is running on. 0xBAC0 == 47808

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you've set the default gateway address - for it to know where to return it's responses, but *only* if necessary.)

If we start with the assumption that maybe the device is not (by default) listening for broadcasts or having some issue sending it - a bug maybe (although probably unlikely), then you could send a unicast/directed message, e.g. use the Read-Property service to read back the (already known) BOIN (BACnet Object Instance Number), but you would need a (BACnet) client (application/software) that provides that option, like possibly one of the 'BACnet stack' cmd-line tools or maybe via the (for most part) awesome (but advanced-level) 'VTS (Visual Test Shell)' tool.

As much as it might be possible to discover what the device's BOIN (BACnet Object Instance Number) is, it's better if you know it already (- as a small few device's might not make it easy to discover - i.e. you might have to resort to using a round-robin bruteforce approach, firing lots of requests - one after the other with only the BOIN changed/incremented by 1, until you receive/see a successful response).